# Running Web API on IIS 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-404, iis-6

I get a 404 Error when I try to run my Web API service on IIS 6.  When I run it locally, it works.  On IIS, my virtual directory is running .NET 4.  The framework that my project is running is 4.0.

I have read many posts on this forum regarding the same issue, but haven't found a solution.  Are there any special configuration settings on IIS 6 or code that needs to be written that enables IIS 6 to recognize Web API?  Also, do I need to install MVC?

Comment: IIS6, as in Windows 2003? Dude, upgrade!! Askinng here about a 404 for IIS6.0 lol

Comment: @JeremyThompson Unfortunately, I don't have the authority to do that.

Comment: Windows 2003 isn't even supported anymore! So when you do encounter any IT issues with your servers you are screwed.